# UFT Run as normal user is different from administrator

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I done my Scripting in IE 8 Windows 2008 and the script was working fine .Now my System upgraded to Windows 7 and IE to 11.Now UFT  script doesn't identify the objects . The same UFT identifies correctly if i open UFT Run as Administrator .Why is this change .How to over come

Thanks
Saikrishna

Comment: Check if the "BHOManager class" add-on is enabled in IE

Answer (score 1):

I enabled the BHO Manger Class as mentioned by the Motti and it is working fine

Thanks for all